# Ideas for upgrading code from Tensorflow (v1.0.12 to 1.7+)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, anaconda

I'm currently following a tutorial on Udemy for a Deep NLP Chatbot implementation with Tensorflow. Currently, on the tutorial, he is basing all his code on Tensorflow 1.0.12.

I have played with Tensorflow before and have moderate knowledge of the subject. But I'm having a hard time trying to retrofit the syntax from what the is being taught (in 1.0.12) to Tensorflow 1.7.

The code block in question is this one while building the Seq2Seq Model:

```
# Creating placeholders for the inputs and the targets
def model_inputs():
    inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name = 'input')
    targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name = 'target')
    lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'learning_rate')
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'keep_prob')
    return inputs, targets, lr, keep_prob

# Preprocessing the targets
def preprocess_targets(targets, word2int, batch_size):
    left_side = tf.fill([batch_size, 1], word2int['<SOS>'])
    right_side = tf.strided_slice(targets, [0,0], [batch_size, -1], [1,1])
    preprocessed_targets = tf.concat([left_side, right_side], 1)
    return preprocessed_targets

# Creating the Encoder RNN
def encoder_rnn(rnn_inputs, rnn_size, num_layers, keep_prob, sequence_length):
    lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
    lstm_dropout = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, input_keep_prob = keep_prob)
    encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout] * num_layers)
    encoder_output, encoder_state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw = encoder_cell,
                                                                    cell_bw = encoder_cell,
                                                                    sequence_length = sequence_length,
                                                                    inputs = rnn_inputs,
                                                                    dtype = tf.float32)
    return encoder_state

# Decoding the training set
def decode_training_set(encoder_state, decoder_cell, decoder_embedded_input, sequence_length, decoding_scope, output_function, keep_prob, batch_size):
    attention_states = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1, decoder_cell.output_size])
    attention_keys, attention_values, attention_score_function, attention_construct_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention(attention_states, attention_option = "bahdanau", num_units = decoder_cell.output_size)
    training_decoder_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_train(encoder_state[0],
                                                                              attention_keys,
                                                                              attention_values,
                                                                              attention_score_function,
                                                                              attention_construct_function,
                                                                              name = "attn_dec_train")
    decoder_output, decoder_final_state, decoder_final_context_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_rnn_decoder(decoder_cell,
                                                                                                              training_decoder_function,
                                                                                                              decoder_embedded_input,
                                                                                                              sequence_length,
                                                                                                              scope = decoding_scope)
    decoder_output_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(decoder_output, keep_prob)
    return output_function(decoder_output_dropout)

# Decoding the test/validation set
def decode_test_set(encoder_state, decoder_cell, decoder_embeddings_matrix, sos_id, eos_id, maximum_length, num_words, decoding_scope, output_function, keep_prob, batch_size):
    attention_states = tf.zeros([batch_size, 1, decoder_cell.output_size])
    attention_keys, attention_values, attention_score_function, attention_construct_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention(attention_states, attention_option = "bahdanau", num_units = decoder_cell.output_size)
    test_decoder_function = tf.contrib.seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_inference(output_function,
                                                                              encoder_state[0],
                                                                              attention_keys,
                                                                              attention_values,
                                                                              attention_score_function,
                                                                              attention_construct_function,
                                                                              decoder_embeddings_matrix,
                                                                              sos_id,
                                                                              eos_id,
                                                                              maximum_length,
                                                                              num_words,
                                                                              name = "attn_dec_inf")
    test_predictions, decoder_final_state, decoder_final_context_state = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_rnn_decoder(decoder_cell,
                                                                                                                test_decoder_function,
                                                                                                                scope = decoding_scope)
    return test_predictions

# Creating the Decoder RNN
def decoder_rnn(decoder_embedded_input, decoder_embeddings_matrix, encoder_state, num_words, sequence_length, rnn_size, num_layers, word2int, keep_prob, batch_size):
    with tf.variable_scope("decoding") as decoding_scope:
        lstm = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size)
        lstm_dropout = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm, input_keep_prob = keep_prob)
        decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout] * num_layers)
        weights = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1)
        biases = tf.zeros_initializer()
        output_function = lambda x: tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x,
                                                                      num_words,
                                                                      None,
                                                                      scope = decoding_scope,
                                                                      weights_initializer = weights,
                                                                      biases_initializer = biases)
        training_predictions = decode_training_set(encoder_state,
                                                   decoder_cell,
                                                   decoder_embedded_input,
                                                   sequence_length,
                                                   decoding_scope,
                                                   output_function,
                                                   keep_prob,
                                                   batch_size)
        decoding_scope.reuse_variables()
        test_predictions = decode_test_set(encoder_state,
                                           decoder_cell,
                                           decoder_embeddings_matrix,
                                           word2int['<SOS>'],
                                           word2int['<EOS>'],
                                           sequence_length - 1,
                                           num_words,
                                           decoding_scope,
                                           output_function,
                                           keep_prob,
                                           batch_size)
    return training_predictions, test_predictions

# Building the seq2seq model
def seq2seq_model(inputs, targets, keep_prob, batch_size, sequence_length, answers_num_words, questions_num_words, encoder_embedding_size, decoder_embedding_size, rnn_size, num_layers, questionswords2int):
    encoder_embedded_input = tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence(inputs,
                                                              answers_num_words + 1,
                                                              encoder_embedding_size,
                                                              initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(0, 1))
    encoder_state = encoder_rnn(encoder_embedded_input, rnn_size, num_layers, keep_prob, sequence_length)
    preprocessed_targets = preprocess_targets(targets, questionswords2int, batch_size)
    decoder_embeddings_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([questions_num_words + 1, decoder_embedding_size], 0, 1))
    decoder_embedded_input = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(decoder_embeddings_matrix, preprocessed_targets)
    training_predictions, test_predictions = decoder_rnn(decoder_embedded_input,
                                                         decoder_embeddings_matrix,
                                                         encoder_state,
                                                         questions_num_words,
                                                         sequence_length,
                                                         rnn_size,
                                                         num_layers,
                                                         questionswords2int,
                                                         keep_prob,
                                                         batch_size)
    return training_predictions, test_predictions
```

Things like `tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention()` and `tf.contrib.seq2seq.attention_decoder_fn_train()` no longer exist, and though I'm trying to map out the references on the Tensorflow website, it's hard to wrap my head around what changed between tf 1.0 and tf 1.7. Also, I don't want to have to downgrade if possible, I would like to keep everything shiny and new.